# push notification in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, foreground

I have an application with ability to receive *Push Notifications*.

When the application is in *background* mode push notification shows well, but if the application is in *foreground* mode I want to show my `custom view` with information from `userInfo`.

How can I notify any `viewController` from my appDelegate `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to show this custom view and send `userInfo` dictionary there?

Can someone help me with my problem?

Comment: it is enough to notify the root navigation- or tab bar- or split view controller... and how? maybe post a notification to them...?

Comment: If you want to add a custom View then you can simply add it to Window like this [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:overlayView]; no Need to Inform any other View Controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data received from a push notification from the AppDelegate to a ViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300144/passing-data-received-from-a-push-notification-from-the-appdelegate-to-a-viewcon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send out a notification and then the viewControllers that you want to be alerted can have observers for them:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("nameOfNotification", object: yourVariableContainingUserInfo)
```

Can you add observers like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "nameOfNotification:", name: "nameOfNotification", object: nil)
```

And your selector would look something like this:

```
func nameOfNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let dict = notification.object as? NSDictionary {
        //user your userInfo dictionary here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **NSNotificationCenter** to notify your viewcotroller from the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Then you can show custom view as you want with the userinfo dictionary passed in that **NSNotificationCenter** method .